# save auditing class on which operations are performed in revision entity with hibernate-envers

Tags: java, logging, hibernate-envers

I want to save a auditing log from different fields of a table in save, edit and delete operations. I used **Hibernate-envers**. But when saving the auditing log, I want to save the class name of the auditing log as well. I used **EntityTrackingRevisionListener**, but its method is called after saving the auditing log. Can anyone help me?

**My class :**

```
 import javax.persistence.*;
 import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.Set;

 import static org.hibernate.envers.RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED;


 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "ADT_COMPANY")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName =      
 "SEQ_ADT_COMPANY", allocationSize = 1, schema = "AUDITDB")
 public class Company extends BaseEntity<Integer> {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
private Company parent;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Company> children;

@Audited
@NotNull
@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Audited
@Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
private String fullName;

@Audited
@Column(name = "FULL_PATH")
private String fullPath;

@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "TREE_LEVEL", nullable = false)
private CompanyLevelEnum treeLevel;
```

**Audit class :**

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "ADT_COMPANY_AUDIT")
 public class CompanyAudit {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;

@MapsId
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Company company;

@Column(name = "REVISION_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer revision;

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "REVISION_TYPE", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private RevisionType revisionType;

@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "FULL_NAME", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "FULL_PATH", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String fullPath;`
```

**RevisionEntity :**

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
 @org.hibernate.envers.RevisionEntity(RevisionListener.class)
 @Table(name = "REVISION")
 public class RevisionEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@RevisionNumber
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer id;

@RevisionTimestamp
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "MODIFIED_DATE", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Date modifiedDate;

@Column(name = "PERSIAN_MODIFIED_DATE", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String persianModifiedDate;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MODIFIED_BY", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private User modifiedBy;

@Column(name = "ip", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String ip;

@Column(name = "ENTITY_CLASS_NAME", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String entityClassName;`
```

**RevisionListener :**

```
 @Component
 public class RevisionListener implements EntityTrackingRevisionListener, org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener {

 private String modifiedEntityName=" ";

@PrePersist
@Override
public void entityChanged(Class entityClass, String entityName, Serializable entityId, RevisionType revisionType, Object o) {
    this.modifiedEntityName = entityClass.getName();
    
}


@Override
public void newRevision(Object o) {
    RevisionEntity revisionEntity = (RevisionEntity) o;
    revisionEntity.setPersianModifiedDate(DateUtility.todayfa());
    revisionEntity.setModifiedBy(SecurityUtility.getAuthenticatedUser());
    revisionEntity.setIp(SecurityUtility.getRequestedIp());
    revisionEntity.setEntityClassName(modifiedEntityName);
}`
```

i want call **entityChanged** method before **newRevision**

or

how to set **EntityClassName**